# Show that for $n\gt 2$, $\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{n}\lt H_n$

Tags: harmonic-numbers, divisor-sum

Is there any positive integer $n$, besides $n=2$ such that
$$\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{n}=H_n$$

They are clearly asymptotic from their graphs so can we show that for $n\gt 2$, $$\frac{\sigma_1(n)}{n}\lt H_n$$

Comment: Actually the opposite inequality is always true.

Comment: @Crostul thanks. I meant that. :)

Answer (score 1):

For $n \ge3$,
$$\frac{\sigma_1 (n)}{n} = \sum_{d|n}\frac{d}{n} = \sum_{d|n}\frac{1}{d} < \sum_{d=1}^n \frac{1}{d}=H_n$$

Comment: I believe that in your answer maybe there is a typo, you need to write $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n}d=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{n}{d}$ for your cases.

Comment: @user243301: Here we have just a reversal of the order of summation:  $d\to\frac{n}{d}$. (+1)

Comment: Now I see that I was confused @MarkusScheuer thus my apologizes to you and the user answering the question.